# How to query XMLConfiguration by value with XPath in Apache Commons Configuration?

Tags: java, xpath, apache-commons-config

So I have the following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<omg>
  <configurationCreated>23/05/20 01:19:30</configurationCreated>
  <sites>
    <site>
      <name>qwer1</name>
      <another>lol1</another>
    </site>
    <site>
      <name>qwer2</name>
      <another>lol2</another>
    </site>
  </sites>
</omg>
```

I am trying to query the `site` with name `qwer2` in order to check whether it already exists inside the file. How do I do this?

This is what I tried in Java (I kinda followed this [guide](http://mbukowicz.github.io/2012/05/05/configuration-that-rocks-with-apache.html)).

```
Parameters parameters = new Parameters();

FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration> builder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration>(XMLConfiguration.class)
    .configure(parameters
        .xml()
        .setFileName("mahfile.xml")
        .setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine()));

builder.setAutoSave(true);

try {
  configuration = builder.getConfiguration();
} catch (ConfigurationException e) {
  return;
}

configuration.getList("omg/sites[site[name='qwer2']]")
```

Unluckily I am getting an empty list (and can't check the size of it (in order to check how many sites are inside)) so the query seems to fail. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried `omg/sites/site[name='qwer2']` which works with [this xpath exerciser](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) but not in my code, I'm still getting an empty list.

Comment: It might be easier to use `XPathFactory` (compile+evaluate) and an XPath expression like : `count(//name[.="qwer2"])>0` (returns true) to check the presence of the element.

Comment: Is `XPathFactory` part of Apache Commons Configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Glad you found a solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after extensive doc reading and playing around I found that that's the best way to count the elements and tell whether my xml node already exists. `configurationsAt()` return xml nodes, which are called 'hierarchical configuration objects' in this case.

```
configuration.configurationsAt("//site[name = 'qwer2']").size()
```